# Script slow on ipad and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I have a script to animate elements with a data attribuut. This is the script.

```
// fade in the elements one by one.
function showContent() {
    var toAnimate = $('.animate-content');
    // put in the correct order.
    toAnimate.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.getAttribute('data-sequence') > b.getAttribute('data-sequence');
    });

    toAnimate.each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(500 * i).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    });
}

// start fading in the elements after a delay.
setTimeout(showContent, 250);
```

But this script making the website super slow on an iPad and Safari. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Why this script making my website verry slow

Comment: Put this script into separate `js` file

Comment: Not sure if this is related: http://ajaxian.com/archives/ipad-javascript-shockingly-slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var toAnimate = $('.animate-content');
toAnimate.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.getAttribute('data-sequence') > b.getAttribute('data-sequence');
});

function showContent() {
    toAnimate.each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(500 * i).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    });
}

setTimeout(showContent, 250);
```